# xmlhttprequest　onloadが呼ばれずonerrorしか呼ばれない

Tags: javascript, html

xmlhttprequestを使ってみようと思い以下のようなコードを書いたのですが、
onloadが実行されず必ずonerrorが呼び出されます。
どうすればonloadが呼び出されるでしょうか

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function fn()
{
    alert("RUN!");
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url="http://www.yahoo.co.jp";

    xhr.open("GET", url, true);

    xhr.onload = function (oEvent) {
        alert("on load");
    };

    xhr.onerror=function(oEvent){
        alert("on error");
    }
    xhr.send(null);
};
</script>
</head>

<body>
<button type="button" name="btn" onclick="fn()">ボタン</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: 書くの忘れましたがブラウザはクロームのバージョン: 67.0.3396.99（Official Build） （64 ビット）としてください。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

あるWebサイトから別の悪意のあるWebサイトの情報を読み込んで実行させないための仕組みとして`Same-Origin Policy(同一生成元ポリシー)`というのがブラウザ、Yahoo!Japanで適応されているため、`xhr`や`fetch`で情報を取得することが出来ません。

もしYahoo!JapanのWebサイトの内容を読み込んでこのJSの`onload`のほうを実行させるためにはYahoo!Japanのサーバー側で貴方のドメインからの読み込みを可能に(CORS対応)してもらう必要があります。

CORS(Cross Origin Resource Sharing)に関しては以下を見るとわかりやすいと思います。
https://qiita.com/tomoyukilabs/items/81698edd5812ff6acb34

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
大雑把に言ってサーバー側の許可が必要で、クライアント側だけでは解決しないということですか。
クライアント側だけしか見ていませんでした。

Comment: はいそのとおりです。セキュリティ設定などで仕方ないですね。